# Who were the first heroes to go on an adventure because their hometown was destroyed during a festival?

Tags: history-of, trope

In Wheel of Time (2021) S1E1 the heroes embark on their adventure because their hometown is destroyed during a festival. I assume the same happens in *The Eye of the World* but I don't know for certain. Were they the first adventurers to start that way, or did someone else do it first?

Going on some quest because your hometown is destroyed is an old trope. The oldest I've found quickly is from Jack Vance's *The Demon Princes* in 1964.
Having a town being destroyed during a festival is also older, such as in Gabriel Garcia-Marquez's *One Hundred Years of Solitude*.
Who was the first to combine the two?

Comment: Pretty sure you can track down a quote of Robert Jordan explaining that the similarities to lotr are on purpose, to draw readers in with a sense of familiarity.

Answer (score 2):

Valinor was attacked and the Two Trees destroyed during a festival, which caused the Noldor to go forth in pursuit of Melkor and the stolen Silmarials. I wouldn't exactly call this a quest, but it is not far from one.  This dates to the *Book of Lost Tales*, somewhere between 1916 and 1925.

Comment: But the first pulication date of any version of the return of the Noldor to Middle-earth to fight Morgoth is highly uncertain.  The Book of Lost Tales was not published until 1983 & 1984,  while Tolkien's later version in the Quenta Silmarillion was published in The Silmarillion in 1977, and the return of the Noldor to Middle Earth to get the Silmarilis back from Morgoth was mentioned several times during The Lordof the Rings and its appendixes published in 1955-1955.  And possibly some information on the topic might have been published earlier.